# Must declare the scalar variable error for stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure validateLogin    
(    
 @password varchar(200),    
 @username varchar(100),  
 @IpAddress   varchar(100)  
)    
AS    
BEGIN    
   Declare @qry varchar(max), @LockedIp varchar(max), @LockedTime DateTime, @TimeDifference int;    

   set @qry = 'select IdUser, UserName, FirstName, LastName, idOrg, Users.idRole, Roles.Title as [Role], Allowed_IP from Users, Roles where Users.idRole = Roles.idRole    
 and lower(UserName) = @username and [password] = @password' ;    

   select 
       @LockedIp = isnull(Allowed_IP,''),
       @LockedTime = isnull(LockedTime, getDate()) 
   from Users 
   where UserName = ISNULL(@username,'');    

   SELECT 
       @TimeDifference = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @LockedTime, GETDATE())    

   IF exists(select * from Users where UserName = @username AND Password = @password AND Active = 1)    
   BEGIN     
       IF exists(select * from Users where UserName = @username AND isnull(IsLocked, 0) = 1)    
       BEGIN -- BE1    
          IF(@LockedIp = @IpAddress)     
          BEGIN --BE2    
             IF (@TimeDifference >5)    
             BEGIN --BE5    
                 UPDATE Users 
                 SET IsLocked = 0, LockedTime = null 
                 WHERE UserName = ISNULL(@username,'')  

                 exec(@qry);    
             END --BE5    
          ELSE     
          BEGIN    
             select 'Your Account has been Locked.Try after some time' as Error    
          END    
       END --BE2    
    Else IF(@LockedIp!=@IpAddress)     
     BEGIN --BE4    

        UPDATE Users 
        SET IsLocked = 0, LockedTime = null 
        WHERE UserName = isnull(@username,'')  

        exec(@qry);    
     END --BE4    
    END -- BE1    
   Else    
    BEGIN --BE3    
       exec(@qry);    
    END -- BE3    
 END      
END 
Go
```

When I execute this through:

```
exec validateLogin '|161|217|4|51','admin','127.0.0.1'
```

I get following error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@username".

I have declared this variable in my parameter list, then also error is showing up.

Please help me.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Your variables have limited scope; when you call `exec(@qry)` the variables do no pass through.  Look in to using `sp_executesql` instead of `exec`, it has syntax that allows you to pass in parameters.   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848746.aspx

Comment: will this be done??  set @qry ='select IdUser,UserName,FirstName,LastName,idOrg,Users.idRole,Roles.Title as [Role],Allowed_IP from Users,Roles where     
 Users.idRole=Roles.idRole
 and lower(UserName)='+@username+' and [password]='+@password     ;

Comment: That works, but it's a bad idea for all sorts of reasons *(sql injection attacks, no execution plan re-use, difficulty to read and debug, forgetting to correctly imbed `'` and escape characters, malformed strings for different data types, etc, etc)*.  I strongly recommend using `sp_execuetsql` instead of `exec`.

Comment: but i am going to execute this in .net, so using executenonquery()... its not also running in .net and on local sqlserver i tried with exec,,then also not ran..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EXEC() will execute in a different scope, so your parameters are not found. You should use `sp_executesql` and add your parameters that way:

```
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @qry = N'select IdUser,UserName,FirstName,LastName,idOrg,Users.idRole,Roles.Title as [Role],Allowed_IP 
            from Users,Roles 
            where Users.idRole=Roles.idRole    
            and lower(UserName)=@username 
            and [password]=@password' ;   


EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry, 
                    N'@username varchar(100), @password varchar(200)', 
                    @Username, 
                    @Password;
```

Comment: but i am going to execute this in .net, so using executenonquery()... its not also running in .net and on local sqlserver i tried with exec,,then also not ran..

Comment: How you call the procedure is not really relevant... You just need to replace each instance of `exec(@qry)` with `EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry, N'@username varchar(100), @password varchar(200)', @Username, @Password;`. Although I would not advise using ExecuteNonQuery() if you are expecting results!